# How can I pass slash and other 'url sensitive' characters to a WCF REST service?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, url

I have a REST WCF service that has a method that gets a parameter as a string. This string can contain slash / character. It makes my request wrong, as I think the URL goes wrong.

When requesting it and getting response (WebRequest.GetResponse()) throws "The remote server returns an error: (400) Bad Request." exception.

My request: http://localhost:17679/testmethod/DmC/TCGlOLz1EbEwqAls5Q==\nh2cQzTizSBg=

I tried to use Uri.EscapeDataString, but it does not help, I get the same exception as above.
After this conversion my request looks like this:
http://localhost:17679/testmethod/DmC%2FTCGlOLz1EbEwqAls5Q%3D%3D%0Ah2cQzTizSBg%3D

If I pass a string without slash in the string it works as I want.

How can I pass slash and other 'url sensitive' characters to a WCF REST service?

Thx.

**UPDATE: I solved it, you can see it in my answer bellow.**

Comment: Why is that unacceptable? Does it not get decoded by WCF? If so what does your function see? Is an exception thrown? Did you set includeExceptionDetailInFault as described in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx).

Comment: So, the "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." exception comes when calling WebRequest's GetResponse method.

Comment: Your question did not make it clear that passing the escaped text also returned the 400 error. Please edit it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it.

URI template is the key.

If I define URI this way, it produces the exception above:

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/testmethod/{testvalue}"/*, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml*/)]
string TestMethod(string testvalue);
```

By modifying this way, it works:

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/testmethod?v={testvalue}"/*, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml*/)]
string TestMethod(string testvalue);
```

Anyway, `Uri.EscapeDataString` is needed!

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer will work in some cases, where the URI parameter is at the end of the URI, it will not work if a URI parameter is in the middle of a URI. But with just a few configuration settings, you can allow your application to accept encoded forward slashes.

The `HttpListener` that takes incoming requests uses an internal `HttpListenerRequestUriBuilder` to parse the raw request URI.

The `HttpListenerRequestUriBuilder` will or will not unescape the encoding based on a setting. Add the following setting to your `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpListener unescapeRequestUrl="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

This will allow the incoming `Message`'s `To` headers to be correctly built without unescaping the URIs.

If you are using a version of .NET before 4.5, I believe you may also need to add another setting instructing the `System.Uri` class to not escape slashes for `http` and `https` paths. This setting is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
      <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

`Uri.Match` and the default `QueryStringConverter` should still work with the unescaped text, so a method like:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foos/{bar}/baz"]
public Baz GetFooBaz(string bar)
{
    // ...
}
```

will provide an unescaped string to the `bar` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a \ before each /. (normally it forces the metacharacters to be read as a normal character)