# How to handle escape characters (pipe |) in URL (Spring, REST, CXF)?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat7, cxf

I am using Spring, CXF, Tomcat for developing web services.

I have a problem sending characters such as pipes(|) in the URL?

For example:
`http://localhost:9080/address/v1/countries/\`|

throws a 500 error, is there a way to handle it and throw custom error code like 404 or even 400?

I tried setting the URIEncoding="UTF-8" on the connector object in server.xml in tomcat. But it did not fix it.

I also tried adding filter-mapping in the web.xml in my application like this:-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can someone point me in what way these kind of URI's can return a custom error code and message?

Comment: Seems the link below is a related thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176726/how-can-i-pass-slash-and-other-url-sensitive-characters-to-a-wcf-rest-service

Answer (score 9):

please refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp) for url encoding. Say suppose if you want to send Sachin|Tendulkar. You can send as Sachin%7CTendulkar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. %7C is PIPE Character that needs to be used in URL.
following is another example that I used successfully. In this neighborhood name is "**ROOT|RESTFUL**" which is represented as ROOT%7CRESTFUL

> http://localhost:8080/BAE_4_3_API/rest/v1/user/rahul1/neighborhood/ROOT%7CRESTFUL/collaboration/1000/whiteboard