# WCF REST Service - Self Host Windows Service - How to use % in URL

Tags: rest, wcf, self-hosting, webget

I have a REST WCF service that has a method that gets a parameter as a string

When I use the %23 in the Url I got an error message: Endpoint not found!
e.g:

```
-- Id #9999
http://localhost:8000/MyService/GetData/Id/%239999 (%23 means # symbol encoded)
```

If I use without % symbol it works fine

```
http://localhost:8000/MyService/GetData/Id/10

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetData/id/{id}")]
    string GetData(string value);

}
```

I Host the Service on Windows Service:

```
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), "http://localhost:8000");

        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();

        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "MyService");
        WebHttpBehavior httpBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior();         
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(httpBehavior);

        host.Open();
```

I've found this post:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx but it doesn't work since I'm not hosting WCF on IIS I'm hosting it on Windows Service instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this thread:
[How can I pass slash and other 'url sensitive' characters to a WCF REST service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176726/how-can-i-pass-slash-and-other-url-sensitive-characters-to-a-wcf-rest-service)

Solution:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpListener unescapeRequestUrl="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

its not a best pratice to use some special chars in urls. please so consider not using them.

take a look at [MSDN - UriTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Paulo, but the problem is we have special char in the Id. They use this way here and I have to follow.